# Adicionar métodos ao namespace do plugin sem seletor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Estou criando um plugin em js e preciso adicionar alguns métodos a esse plugin.

***Essa é a base do plugin até o momento:***

```
    (function ($) {
    function jarbas(params) {
        ...
    }

    $.fn.jarbas = function (params) {
        // cria funcionalidade a partir do método sem seletor $.jarbas(params);
    }

    // defaults
    $.fn.jarbas.defaults = { ... };

    $.extend({
        jarbas : function (params) {
            switch (typeof params) {
                case 'string':

                    break;
                case 'object':
                    return new jarbas(params);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Na utilização do plugin eu faço (funciona perfeito):

```
$.jarbas({ ... });
$('seletor').jarbas({ ... });
```

é possível criar métodos extendendo o nome do plugin sem a necessidade de seletor? por exemplo:

```
$.jarbas.remapAll();
```

Comment: Sim, isso é possivel, mas e esse `.remapAll()`: como iria saber o que fazer se não passa nenhum argumento ou seletor?

Comment: quanto a isso não tem problema, desde que eu possa chamar o método!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possivel.

Da mesma maneira que fez `$.fn.jarbas.defaults = { ... };` para defenir uma propriedade dessa função pode adicionar um novo método passando uma função:

```
$.fn.jarbas.remapAll= function(){
    // fazer o que quiser;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$.fn.jarbas = function (params) {
    // cria funcionalidade a partir do método sem seletor $.jarbas(params);
}

// defaults
$.fn.jarbas.defaults = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

$.fn.jarbas.remapAll = function () {
    alert('Eureka! Achei o ' + this.defaults.foo + '!');
}

// testar

alert($.fn.jarbas.defaults.foo);
$.fn.jarbas.remapAll ();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, achei que houvesse uma maneira de criar sem .fn visualmente falando! Vlw!

Comment: @Trxplz0 pode fazer só `$.jarbas` (http://jsfiddle.net/mq29zr6p/) mas isso é má prática. O jQuery indica na documentação que deve ser `$.fn.novoMetodo`

Comment: sim no meu caso como eu uso 1 método extensor não funciona só o $.jarbas ele da erro por encontrar o método e não um plugin. De qualquer forma ta respondido! Vou marcar assim que possível!

Quanto a má prática nem sabia, esse .fn não curto não é briga até o resto da vida!

Answer (score 2):

Seu plugin tem um problema de encadeamento (*chaining*) dos objetos jQuery. O que [a documentação recomenda](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) é que seu plugin sempre retorne `this` (se sempre se aplicar a coleções de apenas 1 objeto), ou `this.each(...)`, se o plugin precisa lidar com mais de um objeto selecionado.

Isso permite que você encadeie métodos do jQuery na mesma seleção, por exemplo:

```
$('a').jarbas().show();
```

Do jeito que seu plugin está construído, retornando `new jarbas`, isso não será possível. Também não dá para chamar `$.jarbas();` se você definiu o método em `$.fn`. Você pode, sim, chamar `$.fn.jarbas()`.

Quanto a como fazer o plugin funcionar como *namespace*, [o Sergio já respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44819/74) e não vou repetir o que ele disse. Como funções em JavaScript são objetos, você pode pendurar quaisquer propriedades que quiser nelas. Mas isso é meio estranho no mundo do jQuery. Plugins geralmente dependem dos seletores, e não são usados com namespaces dessa forma. O que me leva a sua pergunta final:

> é possível criar métodos extendendo o nome do plugin sem a necessidade de seletor?

Sim, mas então não faz sentido colocar seus métodos em `$.fn`. O que tem lá é usado como protótipo de objetos jQuery, que são seleções de nós do DOM. Se você quer algo que independa de seletor, defina direto no próprio objeto `jQuery` (ou `$`):

```js
(function($) {
    $.jarbas = function(){
        document.body.innerHTML += "jarbas<br>";
    };
    $.jarbas.remapAll = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML += "jarbas remapped<br>";
    }
}(jQuery));

$.jarbas();
$.jarbas.remapAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, mas ele retorna o $this e a chamada direta ao $.jarbas é gerada pelo extensor no final que me permite obter ou criar um novo objeto dependendo dos parâmetros. No post eu tirei apenas pra encurta-lo. O que eu preciso é usando seletor e sem. Já foi resolvido! Obrigado!